# Where are docker's registered drivers being initialized in the source code?

Tags: go, docker, software-design

I'm trying to understand Docker's source code while also learning Go. One area of Docker that has me confused is inside of [docker/daemon/graphdriver/driver.go](https://github.com/dotcloud/docker/blob/master/daemon/graphdriver/driver.go) on line 75 where the `name` property of the `strings` map is accessed to obtain the function with type `InitFunc`. However, I can't seem to find where `drivers` is initialized with the registered drives, and it seems that needs to be done somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [line 62](https://github.com/dotcloud/docker/blob/master/daemon/graphdriver/driver.go#L62) inside `init()`:

```
func init() {
    drivers = make(map[string]InitFunc)
}
```

And then in each package that depends on it they call `graphdriver.Register`, for [example](https://github.com/dotcloud/docker/blob/c239c8ad9d183a03fd93948061ae79f81c335c32/daemon/graphdriver/btrfs/btrfs.go#L24):

```
func init() {
    graphdriver.Register("btrfs", Init)
}
```

//edit

From http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html about `init()`:

> Each source file can define its own niladic init function to set up
>   whatever state is required. (Actually each file can have multiple init
>   functions.) And finally means finally: **init is called after all the
>   variable declarations in the package have evaluated their
>   initializers**, and those are evaluated only after all the imported
>   packages have been initialized.
>
> Besides initializations that cannot be expressed as declarations, a
>   common use of init functions is to verify or repair correctness of the
>   program state before real execution begins.

Comment: but where is map set with values? what's calling `init`? It's a local function and I don't see any call to it.

Comment: init is automaticly called by Go when a package is imported, and other packages register their handlers inside their own init functions.

Comment: Ahh ok, that was what I didn't understand. Only `init` and not `Init`?

Comment: Yes, I highly recommend going through http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html before you do anything else, great resource.